# Bash script using CURL

Tags: bash, curl

I have some troubles with this script

```
#! /bin/sh
case $1 in
        upssms)
                logger -t upssched-cmd "The UPS has been gone for 30 secs. Warn by sms..."
                /bin/echo "Power failed. System will hibernate soon..." | /usr/bin/curl "https://service.com/sendmsg=Failure!"
                ;;
        upsgone)
                logger -t upssched-cmd "The UPS has been gone for 2 and a half minutes. Hibernating..."
                #/usr/sbin/hibernate      # direct call to hibernate is not allowed by non-root
                /usr/sbin/upsmon -c fsd   # call a shutdown in NUT instead
                ;;
        ups-back-on-power)
                logger -t upssched-cmd "The UPS power has been restored."
                /bin/echo "Power restored." | /usr/bin/curl "https://service.com/sendmsg=Back!"
                ;;
        *)
                logger -t upssched-cmd "Unrecognized command: $1"
                ;;
esac
```

and I can’t figure out where the bug is since I don’t get notification.
Help!

Comment: You don't tell us much: do all the commands fail? Maybe you could concentrate on only one that's failing (i.e. [reduce the problem to something minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). You say you have no notifications: but you do log something. Or doesn't it work? If it doesn't, how do you know that `curl` has any problem? Finally, I don't understand what you are trying to do piping something to `curl` without any option.

Comment: well… all commands fail. I thought there were a faulty syntax in this script, but you’re right: maybe the cause is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Bash gets super touchy about ! marks within double-quotes. I modified the URLS to use the URL Encoded version of the exclamation. Hexidecimal code 21 per ASCII Tables. http://www.asciitable.com/

```
#! /bin/sh
# If your heart is set on using exclamations
# Use this syntax - "sendmsg=Failure"'!' 
case $1 in
    upssms)
            logger -t upssched-cmd "The UPS has been gone for 30 secs. Warn by sms..."
            /bin/echo "Power failed. System will hibernate soon..." | /usr/bin/curl "https://service.com/sendmsg=Failure%21"
            ;;
    upsgone)
            logger -t upssched-cmd "The UPS has been gone for 2 and a half minutes. Hibernating..."
            #/usr/sbin/hibernate      # direct call to hibernate is not allowed by non-root
            /usr/sbin/upsmon -c fsd   # call a shutdown in NUT instead
            ;;
    ups-back-on-power)
            logger -t upssched-cmd "The UPS power has been restored."
            /bin/echo "Power restored." | /usr/bin/curl "https://service.com/sendmsg=Back%21"
            ;;
    *)
            logger -t upssched-cmd "Unrecognized command: $1"
            ;;
esac
```

Comment: Looks like you've forgotten the double quote at the end of `"https://service.com/sendmsg=Back%21`

Comment: just a typo in the post. There is the double quote in the script.